# Need to delete row from lightning datatable in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

**I have a requirement to delete the rows using utility icon in lightning datatable. Used onrowaction, but I don't have any clue what to do in JS method. Can anyone suggest a sample code for it? or explain me through a short logic?**

[image]

*.JS*

```
@track deleteList = [];

handleDelete(event) {
        console.log('event.detail.row : ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail.row));
        this.deleteList = event.detail.row;
}
```

*.HTML*

```
<lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={mergeObjectList} columns={columnsData}
                    onrowaction={handleDelete}
                    hide-checkbox-column show-row-number-column>
                    </lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove the element with [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) or by way of [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
this.mergeObjectList.splice(this.mergeObjectList.findIndex(row => row.Id === event.detail.row.id), 1);
```

Or:

```
this.mergeObjectList = this.mergeObjectList.filter(row => row.id !== event.detail.row.id);
```

Comment: Sadly the first one does not work which is ```Array.prototype.splice``` and the second one is deleting all the rows and makes the table empty.

Comment: @IndreshBhargav The first once needs `@track` on the variable to work. The second should also work, maybe you've mistyped something.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to delete a row with the following code, but the datatable is left with an empty row (it doesn't remove the row, it just removes the data)

```
handleRowAction(event) {
    const action = event.detail.action.name;    // delete
    console.log(action);
    const row = event.detail.row;   // Product2 object
    switch (action) {
        case 'delete':
            const rows = this.data;
            const rowIndex = rows.findIndex(elem => elem.Id === row.Id);
            rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);

            // LWC data binding doesn't detect a call to push.
            let temp = [];
            temp.push(rows);
            this.data = [...temp];

            break;
    }
}
```